# How do I parse URL's from the text

Tags: regular-expression

I have a multiline text file. Some lines have URL's.
What would be the most efficient way to extract those URL's?

I wrote macros and did a bunch of unnecessary things.
Now I'm thinking about regex groups or global command...

text example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#1  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#2 in voluptate velit esse cillum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#3 dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

expectation:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#1
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#2
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tricky part is getting a valid URL. Take some reasonable regex (say `/http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*/` - or if you want to be pedantic, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)). First get the URLs on individual lines, and then delete lines which aren't URLs:

```
:%s/.\{-}\(http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*\)/\1\r/g
:g!//d
```

- The substitution uses a [non-greedy](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#non-greedy) regex to match characters before a URL. Otherwise, if multiple URLs were present in the same line, all but the last would be covered by `.*`.
- The second command specifies an empty regex, reusing the last regex used. The initial `.\{-}` will match the empty string, so this regex can be reused without problems.

If you have `grep` with `-o`:

```
:%!grep -o 'http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]\%\/_\#.-]*'
```

- The `%` and `#` have to escaped to prevent vim from interpreting them.

Comment: For a quicker and dirtier regex use: `http.\?:\/\/\S\+'`. Works with `grep` as well.

Comment: so the shortest way would be
  `%s/.\{-}\(http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*\)/\1\r/g|g!//d`

Comment: The problem with parsing URL's is that it's very very tricky to get all URL's; this will for example fail on `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi_(Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer)`, since it doesn't recognize the `(` ... There is also a disparity between what the standard says, and what browser accept... Not saying this a bad answer (+1 from me), just saying it's very difficult (maybe even impossible?) to get this 100% correct (and most, if not all, sites don't get it 100% correct).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I expected someone to point that out, hence the link to that classic SO post. :D

Comment: Expanding on @PeterRincker's quicker-and-dirtier regex, how about something like (in PCRE, because I'm unfamiliar with Vim's flavor of regex) `/[a-z]+:\/\/\S+/`?