# Ignore URLs and email addresses in spell file

Tags: regular-expression, spell-checking

Is there a way to have vim not flag HTTP URLs and email addresses as spelling errors? Or, more generally, a way to list regexes of valid spellings?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add custom syntax rules, and give them the
[`@nospell`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#spell%2dsyntax) keyword,
this will tell Vim not to apply spell checking to this syntax match. For example:

```
:syn match UrlNoSpell "\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+" contains=@NoSpell
```

The above will work for text files, and *some* filetypes (such as
markdown), but not for all filetypes.

Note that I used a fairly simple regex here; see [How do I parse URL's from the text](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2014/51) for some alternatives.

---

For other filetypes, you need to do a bit more work. For example, for `python` files, comments are contained in a `pythonComment`
group, from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim`:

```
syn match   pythonComment   "#.*$" contains=pythonTodo,@Spell
```

To override this, we need to do:

```
:syn match UrlNoSpellComment "\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+" contains=@NoSpell containedin=pythonComment
:highlight def link UrlNoSpellComment Comment
```

The trick is to add a list of previously matched syntax matches in which our
custom syntax match may be contained with `containedin=` This tells Vim to look for the
`UrlNoSpell` regex *within* the `pythonComment` matches.

We also need to use `highlight` to set the correct colours, since these aren't
inherited.

You need to do this in a number of places, for example for Python strings:

```
:syn match UrlNoSpellString "\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+" contains=@NoSpell containedin=pythonString
:highlight def link UrlNoSpellString String
```

We need 2 different syntax match groups so we can apply the correct syntax highlighting.

Of course, for other filestypes you need to use other `containedin=` syntax
matches... There is, AFAIK, no "universal" solution, but looking up the correct
ones in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/*.vim` should not be too difficult.

---

Note that all of the above commands must be executed *after* the syntax files;
there are 2 ways to do this:

- From a command or key mapping, this must be invoked manually every time. e.g.

  ```
  fun! NoUrlSpell()
      if &filetype == 'python'
          :syn match UrlNoSpellComment "\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+" contains=@NoSpell containedin=pythonComment
          :highlight def link UrlNoSpellComment Comment
          :syn match UrlNoSpellString "\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+" contains=@NoSpell containedin=pythonString
          :highlight def link UrlNoSpellString String
      elseif &filetype == 'ruby'
          " ...
      else
          syn match   pythonComment   "#.*$" contains=pythonTodo,@Spell
      endif
  endfun
  command NoUrlSpell :call NoUrlSpell()
  ```
- Put the commands in in the `~/.vim/after/syntax/[filetype].vim`. Vim will pick up
  these files and execute them *after* the default syntax files (see:
  [`:help after-directory`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#after%2ddirectory)).

Comment: “We also need to use `highlight` to set the correct colours, since these aren't inherited. […] We need 2 different syntax match groups so we can apply the correct syntax highlighting.” You can also mark the matchgroup as being `transparent`. This way, the matched bits keep the style of their containing group and you don’t need a different rule for each containing group. However a `transparent` matchgroup apparently isn’t matched at toplevel, so you’d still need two rules (one for toplevel, one for contained), but that is still simpler.

Comment: It looks like Cecil Curry's newer answer already covers that @Maëlan. I don't think I knew about `transparent` back in 2015.

Comment: Indeed I saw that afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

[Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/martin-tournoij)'s [otherwise excellent answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4003/16249) fails to behave as expected for me – probably due to my leveraging [diraol](https://github.com/diraol)'s [phenomenal `python-mode` plugin](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode) rather than Vim's default syntax file for Python.

To avoid highlighting URIs in Python comments, strings, or docstrings under `python-mode`, add the following concise one-liner to your user-specific `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` file:

```
syntax match NoSpellUriPython '\w\+:\/\/[^[:space:]]\+' transparent contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell
```

**That's it.** Crucially, note that this compresses what would have been *twelve* separate lines in Martin's answer into a single line. How? Elementary, my dear Vim-based Watson. We add:

- The `transparent` keyword, instructing Vim to inherit the highlight properties for this child syntax from its parent syntax (e.g., comments, strings). This enables us to avoid explicitly restating `highlight def link` for each child syntax group.
- The `contained` keyword, preventing this child syntax from extending past the boundaries of its parent syntax (e.g., EOL for comments, string delimiters for strings).
- All parent syntax groups delimited by commas to the `containedin` keyword. The `.*` regex operator enables us to cleverly match *all* Python string syntax groups (i.e., `pythonString`, `pythonUniString`, `pythonRawString`, `pythonUniRawString`, `pythonDocstring`) with minimal pain and maximal forward compatibility.

Although technically valid, the vimscript embedded in Martin's answer violates the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. See also [this similar answer for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2952965/2809027).

But wait... *there's more.*

### Unasked-for Improvements for Great Glory

I'm sufficiently annoyed by both Vim's overly naïve default spell checking *and* third-party plugins (e.g., [Spelunker](https://github.com/kamykn/spelunker.vim), which unconditionally spell checks the entire buffer rather than merely code comments and strings) that I've decided... **to actually do something about that.** `</gasp>`

The [well-tested Vim snippet below](https://github.com/leycec/vimrc/blob/github/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim) intelligently avoids spell checking all of the following within Python comments and strings:

- URIs (as above).
- `CamelCase` identifiers.
- `snake_case` identifiers.
- `UPPERCASE`  identifiers.
- `@`-prefixed identifiers (e.g., `@muhdecorator`).
- `"`-delimited filetyped filenames (e.g., `"muh_module.py"`).
- `:`-delimited substrings (e.g., the `:func:` in :func:`re.sub`).
- `-delimited substrings (e.g., the `re.sub` in :func:`re.sub`).

Add some or all of the following to your user-specific `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` file and gasp in delight as Vim actually spell checks the RightStuff™ for once:

```
" Avoid spell checking URIs.
syntax match NoSpellPythonUri /\v\w+:\/\/[^[:space:]]+/ transparent contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell

" Avoid spell checking both CamelCase-formatted identifiers and uppercase
" identifiers. Since most languages (excluding Raku) prohibit Unicode in
" identifiers, these matches are intentionally confined to ASCII codepoints
" (e.g., "[A-Z]" rather than "[[:upper:]]").
syntax match NoSpellPythonCaps /\v<[A-Z]([A-Z0-9]{-1,}|[a-z0-9]+[A-Z0-9].{-})>/ transparent contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell

"FIXME: For unknown reasons, enabling this and *ONLY* this "syntax" statement
"causes subtle (but horrible) failures across "python-mode" indentation and
"syntax highlighting. While lamentable, we need "python-mode" more than we need
"to avoid spell checking snake_case-formatted identifiers. See also this
"currently unresolved upstream issue:
"    https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/1083
"
" " Avoid spell checking snake_case-formatted identifiers.
" syntax match NoSpellPythonSnake
"   \ /\v<\w+_.{-1,}>/ transparent
"   \ contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell

" Avoid spell checking "@"-prefixed identifiers.
syntax match NoSpellPythonDecorator /\v\@[a-zA-Z].{-}>/ transparent contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell

" Avoid spell checking ":"-delimited substrings.
syntax match NoSpellPythonColons /\v:[^:]+:/ transparent contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell

" Avoid spell checking "`"-delimited substrings.
syntax match NoSpellPythonTicks /\v`[^`]+`/ transparent contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell

" Avoid spell checking '"'-delimited filetyped filenames matched as a
" double-quoted substring containing a filename prefix, a period, and one to
" four characters comprising a filetype.
syntax match NoSpellPythonPath /\v"[^"]+.[^"]{1,4}"/ transparent contained containedin=pythonComment,python.*String contains=@NoSpell
```

Of course, all of the above could (and possibly should) be reduced to a single one-liner matching one Godzilla-like regular expression that no one including myself would ever be able to maintain or even read. For everyone's sanity, I didn't do that.

If someone who is *not* me would like to make a GitHub-hosted Vim plugin expanding the above to other popular languages, that'd be just great. Vim's default spell checking implementation is *almost* there, folks; it just needs a helping hand from the open-source community.

Until then, may the StackOverflow be with you always!

Comment: I kinda figured out this whole Vim syntax highlighting thing while writing answers here. I didn't always know what I was doing to be honest, so especially some of the older answers may be less-than-optimal 

Comment: You're too modest, Martin. Without your "breaking the ice" answer, I and many others wouldn't have even known where to begin. Thanks for getting this editor party started! Rome may not have been built in a day, but at least we can spell check it in one now.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Martin and Cecil’s excellent answers, I came up with this.

All the code I give is to be put in your vimrc, after `:syntax enable` (so that you can plug onto the syntax linter by doing `:au Syntax * ...`).

So, the annoying part in the problem at hand is that you need to specify *for all filetypes you care about, all the matchgroups* in which you want your spelling exception to apply. There is no way around that, but you can relieve the task a bit by defining a cluster. I use this one.

```
au Syntax * syn cluster AllSpell contains=
\cComment,cCommentL,cString,cCppString,
\javaComment,javaLineComment,javaCommentTitle,javaString,
\javascriptComment,javascriptLineComment,jsonString,
\scalaMultilineComment,scalaTrailingComment,
\hsLineComment,hsBlockComment,
\ocamlComment,ocamlString,opamComment,opamString,
\lispComment,lispCommentRegion,lispString,
\makeComment,
\shComment,shSingleQuote,shDoubleQuote,zshComment,
\vimComment,vim9Comment,vimLineComment,vim9LineComment,vimMtchComment,vimString,
\pythonComment,pythonString,pythonRawString,
\luaComment,luaString,luaString2,
\perlComment,perlPOD,
\prologComment,prologCComment,prologString,
\texComment,bibField,bibComment,bibComment2,bibComment3,bibQuote,bibBrace,bibParen,
\xmlComment,xmlString,htmlComment,cssComment,
```

To figure out the matchgroups you want to insert into, you need to look into the code of the linters for the filetypes you care about (e.g. in `/usr/share/vim/vimXX/yourfiletype.vim`). Grepping for `Spell` helps. Typically that will be the matchgroups for comments and string literals.

<del>According to Cecil’s answer you can use wildcards in matchgroup names, so for instance I could have shortened `vimComment,vim9Comment,vimLineComment,vim9LineComment,vimMtchComment` to just `vim.*Comment`. Perhaps catching all of `.*Comment,.*String` would be a good idea, if brutal? Still, not all matchgroup names follow this pattern so you still need to do that work of looking into the linting code.</del> *Edited 2022-06-16: Wildcards are expanded early so this will likely not work, because the matchgroups are not defined yet.*

Then, you can do:

```
au Syntax * syn match Url
  \ "\w\+:\/\/[:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=0-9[:lower:][:upper:]_\-.~]\+"
  \ contains=@NoSpell containedin=@AllSpell transparent
au Syntax * syn match Url
  \ "\w\+:\/\/[:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=0-9[:lower:][:upper:]_\-.~]\+"
  \ contains=@NoSpell
```

This uses a more satisfying regex for URLs (it matches a `protocol://` followed by any succession of [valid URL characters—as per RFC 3986—](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)and Unicode letters).

The first rule matches contained URLs, thanks to the cluster just defined. It has the `transparent` option so that it lets the containing matchgroup style the URL. Because of that option, the rule apparently doesn’t match URLs at toplevel, so a second rule is needed. (Of course, if you wanted to, you could also style the URL differently, e.g. `:hi def link Url Underlined`; then you must remove the `transparent` option and only one rule is needed.)

We can avoid repeating ourselves with a function:

```
fun! MatchNoSpell(group, regex)
  let l:cmd = 'au Syntax * syn match ' . a:group . ' /'.a:regex.'/ contains=@NoSpell'
  exe l:cmd . ' containedin=@AllSpell transparent'
  exe l:cmd
endfun

call MatchNoSpell('Url',
  \ '\w\+:\/\/[:/?#[\]@!$&''()*+,;=0-9[:lower:][:upper:]_\-.~]\+' )
```

This function is useful because it can be used for more spelling exceptions.