# How to configure spell to ignore some environments in LaTeX

Tags: spell-checking, plugin-vimtex

Is there a way to tell vim not to spell-check part of a latex document?
For instance, code block using the `minted` environment or URLs in `\url{}`?

(I'm not sure it's relevant for spell checking but I'm using the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin to edit latex files.)

Comment: See (also) this: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4003/1800

Comment: @Gregoire also mentioned this question in [vimtex/issues/#219](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/219).

Answer (score 11):

You can disable spell checking for syntax items by adding them to a cluster together with `@NoSpell`. You can read `:help spell-syntax` for some information and look at your tex syntax file which most likely contains several examples already. If you type `:tabe $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` you should get the tex syntax file in a new tab. If you then search `/\c@NoSpell` you may see a line like

```
 syn cluster texMathZoneGroup add=@NoSpell
```

The `texMathZoneGroup` cluster has been defined earlier in the script to contain a number of syntax items and here `@NoSpell` is added to the cluster to disable spell checking for these items. I'm afraid I can't say exactly where to best make the change for your particular syntax items as I don't know that syntax file very well. There may be an obvious cluster already where you can simply add `@NoSpell`, or you may have to create a cluster that `contains=` the items in question. It is also a good idea to make a copy of the syntax file in your user runtime directory and apply your changes there rather than change the distributed syntax file, or to apply your changes in a `after/syntax/tex.vim` or other script that runs after the syntax file is loaded.

Since you use a plugin, it may have options related to which items are spell checked. I don't use `vimtex` but Karl Lervåg is pretty active here and if you get his attention could answer that for you.

Comment: There are no such options in `vimtex` today, no. But it seems to make sense to ignore spelling in minted environments, so I might update the plugin correspondingly. Thanks for the nice explanation!

Comment: I looked around in the code and I didn't find an existing region for minted environment so I tried to create my own like this: `syn region mintedZone start="\\begin{minted}" end="\\end{minted}" contains=@NoSpell` but it doesn't seem to help. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Grégoire Please, let us continue this discussion in the [vimtex issue](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/219).

Answer (score 6):

You can add your own syntax rules to e.g. `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`. In order to prevent spell checking inside a command such as `\url`, you can use the following code:

```
syntax match texStatement '\\command' nextgroup=texMyCommand
syntax region texMyCommand matchgroup=Delimiter start='{' end='}' contained contains=@NoSpell
```

Here `texStatement` and `Delimiter` are groups that are defined by the internal syntax plugin, see `:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim`.

If you want to understand the above commands, I can recommend the following help sections:

- [`:h syn-match`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-match)
- [`:h syn-region`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-region)
- [`:h syn-spell`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-spell)
- [`:h spell-syntax`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html#spell-syntax)

Comment: Hi @Karl, thanks I have been using this. Is there a way to do this for an indeterminant number of repetitions of texMyCommand? Some commands can be \command{stuff} or \command{stuff}{morestuff}. I want to also ignore morestuff and as many more that come after. I haven't been able to find this in the syntax helpfiles in vim.

Comment: Figured it out. I used end='}^[{]` to exclude a } followed immediately by { to end the region.

Comment: You could do `syntax region texMyCommand matchgroup=Delimiter start='{' end='}' contained contains=@NoSpell nextgroup=texMyCommand`. But notice that this is _greedy_, which may not always be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For commands you can set `g:vimtex_syntax_nospell_commands` to a list of commands whose argument should be excluded from spell checking.

For example, I have set mine this way:

```
let g:vimtex_syntax_nospell_commands = ['foreign', 'posscite', 'toadd', 'todo', 'fontspec', 'Cref']
```

See `:h g:vimtex_syntax_nospell_commands` for documentation.