# Ignore spell check for LaTeX commands with multiple arguments

Tags: filetype-tex, spell-checking

I have read through a lot of the posts on spell checking LaTeX syntax - [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/how-to-configure-spell-to-ignore-some-environments-in-latex/4524), [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/30991/disable-spell-checking-for-urls-in-bibtex), and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/how-to-configure-spell-to-ignore-some-environments-in-latex).

I am sure the problem is my lack of regex understanding, but I am having trouble configuring it so that LaTeX commands that take multiple arguments (and optional arguments) are ignored. For instance, the `\Cites` command can have any number of optional/argument pairs. I would like to ignore all of them. So whether it is `\Cites[10]{AuthorYear1}[20]{AuthorYear2}` or `\Cites[10]{AuthorYear1}[20]{AuthorYear2}[30]{AuthorYear3}` or even `\Cites[10]{AuthorYear1}{AuthorYear2}[30]{AuthorYear3}` or any combination, the BibTeX keys are ignored from the spell checker.

This is something that can be done in `aspell` quite easily in `~/.aspell.conf` with something like `add-tex-command Cites opopopopopopopopopopopopopopop`. (Of course this assumes there is always an optional argument, which for me is true 99.99% of the time. If not, I can add a tex command where the non-optional argument is first, and then always cite keys without an optional argument first.)

I am not using `vim-tex`. I eventually want to try it out, but I am close to finishing my dissertation and don't really want to change my setup at this point. So if there is a solution for how to do something like:

```
syntax match texStatement '\\Cite' nextgroup=texMyCommandMult
syntax region texMyCommandMult matchgroup=Delimiter start='\[' end='}' contained contains=@NoSpell
```

in my `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` that would be very helpful.

Comment: This stuff has this strange combination of being simple and complex. I have support for this in VimTeX, see here:
https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/4b3ceb9eb7f0e12c239d7ef4262728491aee89ba/autoload/vimtex/syntax/p/biblatex.vim#L25

I understand that you don't want to use it now. But one possibility could be to disable all features except the syntax. I.e., if you install the plugin, then do `let g:vimtex_..._enabled = 0` on all the various enable options except syntax. I believe it should "just work".

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg thanks! I definitely want to try out `vimtex`, so maybe I just need to bite the bullet and spend some time switching over. I am using `vim-latex` (solely because I have been using it for 10 years) and have a lot of "muscle memory", haha.

Comment: I believe  you will find VimTeX to be a nice upgrade from vim-latex. Feel free to open issues on the github repo if you have any problems, or contact me on the gitter/element chat if you need advice.