# Spellcheck only a part of a word

Tags: syntax-highlighting, spell-checking

(There might be an XY problem in the title, I let you judge.)

The default dictionary for French sets the (ASCII) hyphen `-` to be a word character, which is the right thing to do. The issue is that French also has some systematic ways of compounding certain words using hyphens¹, and the dictionary doesn’t provide these combinations (there would be *really many* of them). So a perfectly valid French text raises annoyingly many false positives.

The compounds I’m interested in are of the form `XXX-YYY` where `XXX` ranges over all dictionary words (of a certain category: verbs, nouns, etc.) but `YYY` is a known pattern. So I figured I would use regexes to disable spellchecking on words that end with `-YYY`, [thanks to `:syntax match ... contains=@NoSpell`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3990):

```
au Syntax * syn match SuffixedByYYY '\w\+-YYY' containedin=@AllSpell contains=@NoSpell
" (where `AllSpell` is a cluster that lists all matchgroups
" in which I want spelling to be done)
```

This works, but then the arbitrary string `XXX` is not spellchecked at all. I want `XXX` to be spellchecked as a word *per se*. I tried various things, such as applying `contains=@NoSpell` only to the suffix `-YYY`, or applying `contains=@Spell` only to the prefix `XXX`… To no avail. Here is an attempt that subsumes other attempts:

```
au Syntax * syn match SuffixedByYYY
  \ '\w\+-YYY'
  \ keepend
  \ contained
  \ containedin=@AllSpell
  \ contains=@NoSpell,XXX,YYY
au Syntax * syn match XXX '\w\+' keepend contained contains=@Spell
au Syntax * syn match YYY '-YYY' keepend contained contains=@NoSpell
```

It seems that spellchecking ignores the end of matchgroups: when enabled, it decides what is the next word to be spellchecked by consuming the maximal sequence of word-characters, *even if it runs past the current matchgroup*. So whatever I try, the whole compound `XXX-YYY` is signaled as a bad word, regardless of `XXX` being a good word or not.

**Is there anything I can do to spellcheck just `XXX` in `XXX-YYY` when `-` is a word character?**

Remark: the problem of spellchecking `XXX` in `YYY-XXX`² is simpler and can be achieved like this:

```
au Syntax * syn match PrefixYYY 'YYY-\(\w\+\)\@=' containedin=@AllSpell contains=@NoSpell
```

---

¹: The most notable class of such compounds are conjugated verbs followed by one or several pronouns (e.g. `donne-les-moi`, “give them to me”). That alone makes up for tens of possible compounds per verb. There are also some adverbs that can be appended to any noun (e.g. `ce jour-là`, “on *that* day”). And probably other stuff I can’t think of right now.
²: Which is also useful for French, for elisions (e.g. `l'apostrophe` or `j'aime` or `qu'a-t-il`…).